# Simple way associate elements and make proper ones appear on button click

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build a restaurant menu. Initially, the user will only see `div` elements with the title of each section, when one is clicked, the associated dishes should be displayed to the user. I am going to share my attempted solution but feel I am doing this in a convoluted way. If you read this and know a better way to implement what I am trying to do please share.

To briefly explain the html: Each `.section` of the menu( i.e appetizers, entrees) is a `div` containing a `.section-header` `div` and an `.entry` `div` for each entry of that section (.i.e Fried Calmari, Mozzarella Sticks). 
Html:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="section-header appetizers">Appetizers</div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Stuffed Mushrooms</div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Zucchini Sticks</div>
      <div class="description">Served with marinara sauce</div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have made it (using js) so that the `.section-header` divs and `.entry` divs of each `.section` all share a class in common (in this case `.appetizers`). I do this so I can then capture the proper class to apply `display:block` on:

```
let sectionHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('section-header'); //
for(i = 0; i < sectionHeaders.length; i++){
  sectionHeaders[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Right now this.className = 'section-header appetizers'(or entrees, etc).
    // by splitting at the " " it creates an array equal to ['section-header', 'appetizers'].
    // The pop() method then removes the last element and returns it. Leaving targetClass equal to
    // 'appetizers'.
    let targetClass = this.className.split(" ").pop(); // only elements that should be redsiplayed will have this class

    //After this I was going to try and target all div elements with targetClass and apply display:block; to those but stopped because I feel I am doing this wrong.
  }
)};
```

This method of finding and redisplaying the proper `.entry` elements seems like the wrong way to go about this. On top of the code I wrote to generate said elements with the proper classnames (which I'm not is important or not, it's very long but I will leave it under this just in case) I feel my approach to this was entirely wrong. Anyway, if you read all of that and have a simple solution, please share and thanks in advance!

js:

```
let menu = [
  [
      'Appetizers',
      ['Stuffed Mushrooms', "", '$6.95'],
      ['Zucchini Sticks', "Served with marinara sauce", '$6.95']
    ],
    [
      'Soups',
      ['Chicken Noodle','','$4.95'],
      ['Minestrone','','$4.95'],
      ['Lentil','','$5.95'],
      ['Pasta Fagioli','','$5.95'],
      ['Cheese Tortellini','','$6.95'],
    ]
]

//Generate Table of Contents
tocUlElement = document.getElementById('toc-list'); //gets ul element. append li elements to this element
tocItems = generateTOCItemsAsArray(menu); // i.e ['Appetizers', 'Entrees', 'Desserts']
for(i = 0; i < tocItems.length; i++){
  liElement = document.createElement("li"); //create list item element
  liElement.classList.add("toc-list-item"); //give class to list item element
  aElement = document.createElement('a'); //create link element
  aElement.innerHTML = tocItems[i]; // give link text
  aElement.setAttribute('href', '#'); //leave href blank for now
  liElement.appendChild(aElement); //append link to list item
  tocUlElement.appendChild(liElement); //append list item to ul
}

//Generate Menu
let menuDiv = document.getElementById('menu') // represents entire menu
for(i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  let section = document.createElement('div'); // one section of the menu (i.e Appetizers)
  section.classList.add('section');
  for(j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++){
    if(j == 0){ // menu[i][0] is a string representing the name of the section i.e 'Appetizers'
      let sectionHeader = document.createElement('div'); // will contain heading to be displayed if user is on desktop and if user is on mobile
      sectionHeader.classList.add('section-header');
      sectionHeader.classList.add(menu[i][0].toLowerCase()); // button will share this class with each entry element so that the proper ones can be shown when button is clicked
      sectionHeader.innerHTML = menu[i][j]; // i.e 'Appetizers', 'Entrees', etc
      section.appendChild(sectionHeader); // append .section header to entire section (.section)
    }
    else{ //Every element after menu[i][0] is is an array representing a menu entry in the form of [food, description, price]
      let entry = document.createElement('div'); // div represents a single entry, it consits of 3 divs, one for the name of the food, description and price
      entry.classList.add('entry');
      entry.classList.add(menu[i][0].toLowerCase());
      let nameOfFood = document.createElement('div'); // These three divs will be appended to the entry div
      let description = document.createElement('div');
      let price = document.createElement('div');
      nameOfFood.classList.add('name-of-food');
      description.classList.add('description');
      price.classList.add('price');
      nameOfFood.innerHTML = menu[i][j][0]; // Remember [food, description, price]
      description.innerHTML = menu[i][j][1];
      price.innerHTML = menu[i][j][2];
      entry.appendChild(nameOfFood); //
      entry.appendChild(description);
      entry.appendChild(price);
      section.appendChild(entry); // Append the entry to the section
    } // Repeat this process for every entry remaining in the current array item, ex first iteration is at menu[0]
    menuDiv.appendChild(section); // Append section to the menu
  } // move on to next item in menu variable. Second iteration would be menu[1]
}


let sectionHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('section-header'); //
for(i = 0; i < sectionHeaders.length; i++){
  sectionHeaders[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Right now this.className = 'section-h2 appetizers'(or entrees, etc).
    // by splitting at the " " it creates an array equal to ['section-h2', 'appetizers'].
    // The pop() method then removes the last element and returns it. Leaving targetClass equal to
    // 'appetizers'.
    let targetClass = this.className.split(" ").pop();
    //After this I was going to try and target all divs with targetClass 
    // and display those. Stopped doing this because I feel I am doing it wrong.
  }
)};

/* Function definitions */
function generateTOCItemsAsArray(menu){
  let tocItemsAsArray = []
  for(i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
    tocItemsAsArray.push(menu[i][0]);
  }
  return tocItemsAsArray;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're over-complicating it, you [don't need javascript](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/jmdrre).

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this. I'm going to explain 3.

One way I can think of is to use data attributes. They exist exactly for reasons like this: to add data that you want to retrieve using JavaScript.

```
<div class="section">
   <div data-type="appetizers" class="section-header appetizers">Appetizers</div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Stuffed Mushrooms</div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Zucchini Sticks</div>
      <div class="description">Served with marinara sauce</div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See how I added the `data-type` attribute to the `.section-header` element. Then, in JavaScript, you can retrieve it with something like this:

```
for (let sectionHeader of document.getElementsByClassName('section-header')) { // ES6 way of looping an array. Kinda cool ;-)
    sectionHeader.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let type = this.dataset.type;
        console.log(type); // This will show the `data-type` attribute value
    });
}
```

See how I used the `.dataset` attribute to access `data-type` value. Here you have more documentation on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

By the way, because you are using JavaScript to create the elements and the menu (as a personal opinion, kinda cool way to have a configurable menu. Is also my usual way to go), you have already references to everything, so you don't need actually the `data-*` thingy. I'll go this way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) { // Important, don't forget the `let` keyword when you define a `i` variable in a loop.
    let section = document.createElement('div');
    section.classList.add('section');
    (function () {
        // This anonymous function will encapsulate loop scope. Important in this case as we are going to define a callback inside the loop that will access parent scope.
        let entries = []; // Create an entries array
        for (let j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                let sectionHeader = document.createElement('div');
                // Now that we already have a reference to sectionHeader, attach the 'click' event listener and do our work
                sectionHeader.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    // This is where we have the callback I said before. Will access the parent scope "entries" array, which is independent for each loop
                    for (let entry of entries) {
                        entry.doWhatEverYouWant();
                    }
                });
                /*[...]*/
            } else {
                let entry = document.createElement('div');
                entries.push(entry); // Add this entry to the entries array
                /*[...]*/
            }
        }
    })(); // Note how I call the anonymous function with this weird })(); so it runs just when is created. Is like creating a function named pepe and then calling pepe() just after creating it.
    menuDiv.appendChild(section);
}
```

And the third way I can think of is, because you have each list encapsulated inside its own `section`, is easy to access its `.section.entry` to select the elements that you want:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="section-header appetizers">Appetizers</div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Stuffed Mushrooms</div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry appetizers">
      <div class="name-of-food">Zucchini Sticks</div>
      <div class="description">Served with marinara sauce</div>
      <div class="price">$6.95</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The HTML is exactly the same as you have. but you have a difference between the section header and the entries. Tne entries have the `entry` class, then you could do:

```
let sectionHeader = document.createElement('div'); // Or whatever way you want as long as is a reference to the section header, as we said before. You can still use  document.getElementsByClassName('section-header') or whatever you feel more comfortable.

// Now attach the click listener, as always
sectionHeader.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Here comes the magic. You can simple access the parent node...
    let section = this.parentNode;
    //...which will be the <div class="section"> element
    // And now you can select the `.entry` elements and work with them
    for (let entry of section.querySelectorAll(".entry")) {
        entry.doWhateverYouWant();
    }
});
```

As you can see, instead of calling `querySelectorAll` (or `getElementsByClassName`) over the entire `document`, I called it over the `.section` element, so will only find the `.entry` elements inside this element, without going outside.

I can think of more ways, but are more likely variations of this 3. With this 3 you get some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for this above and beyond answer. All things I did not know before and I really appreciate the explanation of choice two.

Answer (score 1):

I would group the entries that belong together in a container element. Then this container element will be immediately following the header element, and you can just toggle the display of that container element.

Also, I would define the click handler on the whole menu, and then check if the clicked element was a header. This saves you from having to define several click handlers.

Define a `hidden` class to easily toggle visibility.

Some remarks on your code:

- don't use `innerHTML` to assign plain text. Use `textContent` for that.
- always declare your variables. Notably the `for` loop variables should not be global.

Here is the code with those adaptations. There are comments where I made changes.

```js
let menu = [
  [
      'Appetizers',
      ['Stuffed Mushrooms', "", '$6.95'],
      ['Zucchini Sticks', "Served with marinara sauce", '$6.95']
    ],
    [
      'Soups',
      ['Chicken Noodle','','$4.95'],
      ['Minestrone','','$4.95'],
      ['Lentil','','$5.95'],
      ['Pasta Fagioli','','$5.95'],
      ['Cheese Tortellini','','$6.95'],
    ]
]

let tocUlElement = document.getElementById('toc-list');
let tocItems = generateTOCItemsAsArray(menu);
for(let i = 0; i < tocItems.length; i++) {
  let liElement = document.createElement("li");
  liElement.classList.add("toc-list-item");
  let aElement = document.createElement('a');
  aElement.textContent = tocItems[i];
  aElement.setAttribute('href', '#');
  liElement.appendChild(aElement);
  tocUlElement.appendChild(liElement);
}

let menuDiv = document.getElementById('menu');
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  let section = document.createElement('div');
  section.classList.add('section');
  let sectionHeader = document.createElement('div'); // move this here
  sectionHeader.classList.add('section-header');
  section.appendChild(sectionHeader);
  let sectionEntries = document.createElement('div'); // create container for the entries
  sectionEntries.classList.add('section-entries', 'hidden'); // initially hide
  section.appendChild(sectionEntries);
  for(let j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++) {
    if(j == 0) {
      sectionHeader.classList.add(menu[i][0].toLowerCase());
      sectionHeader.textContent = menu[i][j];
    }
    else{
      let entry = document.createElement('div');
      entry.classList.add('entry');
      entry.classList.add(menu[i][0].toLowerCase());
      let nameOfFood = document.createElement('div');
      let description = document.createElement('div');
      let price = document.createElement('div');
      nameOfFood.classList.add('name-of-food');
      description.classList.add('description');
      price.classList.add('price');
      nameOfFood.textContent = menu[i][j][0];
      description.textContent = menu[i][j][1];
      price.textContent = menu[i][j][2];
      entry.appendChild(nameOfFood); //
      entry.appendChild(description);
      entry.appendChild(price);
      sectionEntries.appendChild(entry); // Append the entry to the section entries container
    }
    menuDiv.appendChild(section);
  }
}

// Just define one click handler on the whole menu
menuDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // If click was on a header, then toggle the display of the entries container element below it
    if (e.target.classList.contains("section-header")) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden"); 
    }
});

/* Function definitions */
function generateTOCItemsAsArray(menu){
  let tocItemsAsArray = []
  for(i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
    tocItemsAsArray.push(menu[i][0]);
  }
  return tocItemsAsArray;
}
```

```css
.section-header { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px  }
.entry { margin-left: 10px }
.name-of-food { font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px }
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<li id="toc-list"></li>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Finally, I should add that there are many libraries that can provide nice widgets for this, with accordion, collapse/expand, ... and other effects. It is a pity if you would go through all the trouble of creating those from scratch again.

Comment: Thank you for this response. And that last paragraph was a pleasant surprise.